# I'm not able to add column for all rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new in python / pandas, so its probably pretty simple question...but I can't handle it:
I have two dataframe loaded from Oracle SQL. One with 300 rows / 2 column and second with one row/one column. I would like to add column from second dataset to the first for each row as new column. But I can only get it for the first row and the others are NaN.

```
`import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.externals import joblib

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('127.0.1.1', '1521', 'orcl')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='MyName', password='MyPass', dsn=dsn_tns)



d_score = pd.read_sql_query(
'''
SELECT
 ID
,RESULT
,RATIO_A
,RATIO_B
from ORCL_DATA
''', conn) #return 380 rows


d_score['ID'] = d_score['ID'].astype(int)
d_score['RESULT'] = d_score['RESULT'].astype(int)
d_score['RATIO_A'] = d_score['RATIO_A'].astype(float)
d_score['RATIO_B'] = d_score['RATIO_B'].astype(float)


d_score_features = d_score.iloc [:,2:4]
#d_train_target = d_score.iloc[:,1:2] #target is RESULT

DM_train = xgb.DMatrix(data= d_score_features)


loaded_model = joblib.load("bst.dat")
pred = loaded_model.predict(DM_train)


i = pd.DataFrame({'ID':d_score['ID'],'Probability':pred})
print(i)


s = pd.read_sql_query('''select max(id_process) as MAX_ID_PROCESS from PROCESS''',conn) #return only 1 row

m =pd.DataFrame(data=s, dtype=np.int64,columns = ['MAX_ID_PROCESS'] )
print(m)

i['new'] = m     ##Trying to add MAX_ID_PROCESS to all rows

    print(i)



i = 

          ID     Probability
0       20101     0.663083  
1       20105     0.486774 
2       20106     0.441300 
3       20278     0.703176 
4       20221     0.539185 
....
379     20480     0.671976


m = 
     MAX_ID_PROCESS
0       274



i = 

  ID_MATCH  Probability    new
0       20101     0.663083  274.0
1       20105     0.486774    NaN
2       20106     0.441300    NaN
3       20278     0.703176    NaN
4       20221     0.539185    NaN


I need value 'new' for all rows...
```

Comment: So what's in the second data frame? What do you expect it to be adding? An error is only an error relative to some expected output.

Comment: So your first Dataframe has shape 300,2 and second one 1,1 ? Can you please clarify the existing shapes and expected shape of result?

Answer (score 1):

Since your second dataframe is only having one value, you can assign it like this:

```
df1['new'] = df2.MAX_ID_PROCESS[0]

# Or using .loc
df1['new'] = df2.MAX_ID_PROCESS.loc[0]
```

In your case, it should be:

```
i['new'] = m.MAX_ID_PROCESS[0]
```

You should now see:

```
           ID  Probability      new
0       20101     0.663083    274.0
1       20105     0.486774    274.0
2       20106     0.441300    274.0
3       20278     0.703176    274.0
4       20221     0.539185    274.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As we know that we can append one column of dataframe1 to dataframe2 as new column using the code: `dataframe2["new_column_name"] = dataframe1["column_to_copy"]`.

We can extend this approach to solve your problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

df1["ColA"] = [1, 12, 32, 24,12]
df1["ColB"] = [23, 11, 6, 45,25]
df1["ColC"] = [10, 25, 3, 23,15]

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   ColA  ColB  ColC
0     1    23    10
1    12    11    25
2    32     6     3
3    24    45    23
4    12    25    15
```

Now we create a new dataframe and add a row to it.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3["ColTest"] = [1]
```

Now we store the value of the first row of the second dataframe as we want to add it to all the rows in dataframe1 as a new column:

```
val = df3.iloc[0]
print(val)
```

Output:

```
ColTest    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Now, we will store this value for as many rows as we have in dataframe1.

```
rows = len(df1)
for row in range(rows):
    df3.loc[row]=val
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
   ColTest
0        1
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        1
```

Now we will append this column to the first dataframe and solve your problem.

```
df["ColTest"] = df3["ColTest"]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ColA  ColB  ColC  ColTest
0     1    23    10        1
1    12    11    25        1
2    32     6     3        1
3    24    45    23        1
4    12    25    15        1
```